# how to instantiate a class and print the value

Tags: python, class, instantiation

hope somebody can give me a hint here - so i have a Node class that should receive 1 mandatory value and one optional one. The idea is to return a linked list

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, next_node = None):
        self.value = value
        self.next_node = next_node

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next_node
```

Now i'm using this class to create a linked list like:

```
Z = Node('Z')
Y = Node('Y', Z)
X = Node('X', Y)
W = Node('W', X)
```

Now I want to write a function that receives the head of the list and prints it:

```
def print_reverse(head):
    current = head
    my_list = []
    while current:
        current = current.next_node
        u = Node(current)
        my_list.append(u.value)
    print my_list

print_reverse(W)
```

The problem I'm facing is that i get back the memory address instead of the actual value.

```
[<__main__.Node object at 0x1033eb390>, <__main__.Node object at 0x1033eb350>, <__main__.Node object at 0x1033eb310>, None]
```

Basically I don't know how to instantiate the value of the Node. I would want to get back this

```
[ W, X, Y , Z, None]
```

Comment: Why are you doing `u = Node(current)`? Just `my_list.append(current.value)`? Doing `u = Node(current)` makes `u.value = current` which is why you are having this problem.

Comment: @M.Shaw AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, next_node = None):
        self.value = value
        self.next_node = next_node

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next_node

def print_reverse(head):
    current = head
    my_list = []
    my_list.append(current.value)
    while current.next_node != None:
        current = current.next_node
        my_list.append(current.value)
    print my_list

Z = Node('Z')
Y = Node('Y', Z)
X = Node('X', Y)
W = Node('W', X)
print_reverse(W)
```

This runs and prints ['W','X','Y','Z'] for me.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'

Answer (score 0):

You need implement **repr** which should return a printable representation of the object. eg.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, next_node = None):
        self.value = value
        self.next_node = next_node

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next_node

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value
```

[https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**repr**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

Comment: Almost but, to show colection members you need \__repr__ not \__str__. An ugly wart, gone in python 3.